# How to give access to Google calendar - no invitation email sent

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar

There are [steps](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082?hl=en) how to do so. In particular

Share a calendar with specific people

1. On your computer, open Google Calendar. You can’t share calendars
   from the Google Calendar app.
2. On the left, find the “My calendars” section. To expand it, click the Down arrow Down arrow.
3. Hover over the calendar you want to share, and click More More and then Settings and sharing.
4. Under “Share with specific people,” click Add people.
5. Add a person’s or Google group’s email address. Use the drop-down menu to adjust their permission settings. Learn more about
   access permissions.
6. Click Send.
7. The recipient will need to click the emailed link to add the calendar to their list. Learn how to add someone else’s calendar.

Unfortunately the recipient did not receive any email.

The other ways to add other calendar are. But subscribe to calendar works only to my personal calendar. And I do not find correct URL to use to let other to subscribe to my other calendar.

[image]

Could you suggest how to give permission of my gmail calendar to other gmail user?

Comment: I can confirm that using “Share with specific people”, no emails are received by Outlook users at least. See also [Why can't I share only Free/Busy details of my Google Calendar with Outlook user?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/159045/why-cant-i-share-only-free-busy-details-of-my-google-calendar-with-outlook-user) also with zero answers.

Comment: On the flip side, does anyone know how to share a google calendar with someone (who has a google account) *without* sending an email? I want to share the link later, with specific instructions.