# Why can't I share only Free/Busy details of my Google Calendar with Outlook user?

Tags: google-calendar

I need to share my Personal Google calendar with team members (who are not using Google), and who are using Outlook.

- I want to share only Free/Busy information
- I am NOT willing to make this Google calendar public